# Creating a tree given the child and parent pointers

Tags: tree, binary-tree, packing

I have a file containing a set of numbers with their parent number and their child numbers in each line. I want to build a tree out of it in C. How would I go through it?

Example file is given:

```
Thisnode  parentnode  lchildnode  rchildnode

1 14 -1 -1 
2 13 -1 -1 
3 10 -1 -1
4 9 -1 -1 
5 13 -1 -1
6 11 -1 -1
7 9 -1 -1
8 12 -1 -1
9 10 7 4
10 11 3 9
11 12 10 6
12 15 11 8
13 14 2 5
14 15 13 1
15 -1 14 12
```

Comment: Looks like homework, am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There's two parts to completing this task. Building a simple [scanner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Scanner), and organizing an unsorted list into a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) structure.

### Scanner

Create a [finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) with four stages (thisnode, parentnode, lchildnode, rchildnode). When the machine is in the first state (thisnode), allocate a new "unsorted" leaf into the "top" of a list. This list should be large enough to hold all leaf-nodes. Also remember to reset the machine state at the end of the last stage (rchildnode). 
Finally, read a single `char` from input, one at a time, and evaluate the follow conditions.

1. Check for signing (`-`)
2. Check if char is between `0..9` and apply value to a temporary number
3. If `1.` or `2.` are true, read the next number
4. Else apply temporary number to top-leaf, and progress the machine to the next state

### Sorting

Iterate over you unsorted list, and find the "root" element. With the initial value, and children, use a [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) "create" method to populate your binary tree structure. Something like...

```c
struct node {
  int value;
  struct node * left; 
  struct node * right;
};
struct node * create_node(int keyvalue, int lkey, int rkey)
{
  struct node * n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  n->value = keyvalue;
  n->left = 0;   
  n->right = 0;
  if(lkey > -1)
  {
    int llkey = your_iterator_left(lkey);
    int lrkey = your_iterator_right(lkey);
    n->left  = create_node(lkey,llkey,lrkey);
  }
  if(rkey > -1)
  {
    int rlkey = your_iterator_left(rkey);
    int rrkey = your_iterator_right(rkey);
    n->right  = create_node(rkey,rlkey,rrkey);
  }
  return n;
}
```

Not the cleanest, but it'll generate a full binary tree.

[image]

Comment: Is the scanner really needed? Reading 4 `int`s from each line is enough.

Comment: If the data file is binary in nature, no. The presence of `-1` is a give-away to ANSI `atoi` course work.